# Which permission to request from Microsoft Graph to administer Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'd like to administer different tenants remotely using the `Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccessTokens` option. From what I read, one needs to retrieve the token for the tenant through Microsoft Graph. What I do not understand is how and which permission to request.

Is there anyone who has done this and could point me to some documentation or maybe provide an example request? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to determine what are the APIs you want to use. On the “***Modify Permissions (Preview)***” Tab you will be able to see what kind of permissions are needed for that particular API.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
See [Microsoft Graph permissions reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference), [Authentication and authorization basics for Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts), [Authorization and the Microsoft Graph Security API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/security-authorization)